# Silverlight And Prism - Lazy loading a dll outside a xap file?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, prism

In the modularity quick start (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490828.aspx) there is enough details on delay loading a type from an assembly in a xap file.

Is there any way an assembly can be delay loaded using Prism for Silverlight, if it is not embedded in the xap?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a XAP file is just a zip file renamed, so it would be pretty easy to create your own (even on the fly) if you have a dll. There are plenty of tools and/or example code that create zip files. Of course this would mean less download time and server utilisattion as well.